# ASP NET Core 2, Windows Аутентификация и добавление Claims из корпоративной базы данных

Tags: asp.net-core

У нас в компании разрабатывается новое ПО планируется использовать ASP NET Core 2, ПО корпоративное по этому планируется использовать Windows Аутентификацию, но вся информации о пользователях храниться в базе данных. По хорошему после того как пользователь Аутентифицировался информацию о нём нужно добавить в список утверждений Claims для использования например в политиках. Но в какой момент это можно сделать?
Проблема в том, что формы Login нету так как используется Windows Аутентификация.

Comment: Просто заведите мидлварю, в которой переопределяйте свойство User.

Comment: Пишу комментарием а не ответом потому что не знаю тонкостей. Если у кого-то есть желание расписать решение более подробно - пишите.

Comment: может это поможет   
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?tabs=aspnetcore2x или это    

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/

Comment: Спасибо, за ссылки, но я их уже читал.

Comment: Pavel Mayorov буду пробовать, просто наделся, может кто знает другое решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, что я сделал. Тут прочитал как писать [Middleware Components](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.4.php)
Вот что получилось:
У меня есть объект User который содержит информацию о пользователе считанную с базы данных, есть объект реализующий IUserRepository который считывает User из базы данных по имени пользователя которое он берёт из [IIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.principal.iidentity(v=vs.110).aspx)
Далее создаёт Middleware Component:

```
public class AuthorizationMiddleware 
{
    private RequestDelegate _next;
    public AuthorizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IUserRepository repository)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity identity = context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        User user = repository.GetUser(identity);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", user.FullName));
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Дальше регистрируем наш компонент:

```
public coid Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
// ......
app.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMiddleware>();
// ......
}
```

Тут конечно есть ещё над чем поработать, так как при каждом запросе нужно делать запрос в базу, но думаю это можно решить кешированием данных.